# Firefox not opening a promp for saving password on a react form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox

I have a pretty straightforward login component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {observer, inject} from 'mobx-react'
import {Button, Header, Icon, Modal, Message} from 'semantic-ui-react'
import s from 'styled-components'

@inject('uiStore')
@observer
class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      incorrectCredentials: false
    }
  }

  logIn() {

    const {username, password} = this.state

    if (username === '' && password === '') {
      this.props.uiStore.isLoggedIn = true
    } else {
      this.setState({incorrectCredentials: true})
    }
  }

  onInputChange = (event) => {
    const {name, value} = event.target
    //console.log(event.target.value, event.target.name)
    this.setState({[name]: value})
  }

  render() {

    const {incorrectCredentials} = this.state

    return (

      <Modal open={true}>
        <Modal.Content>
          <h3>Please log in to access the application</h3>
          {incorrectCredentials && <Message negative>
            <Message.Header>Incorrect credentials</Message.Header>
            <p>Please input the correct username and password and try again.</p>
          </Message>}
          <LoginStyle>

            <form>
              Username<br/>
              <input className='login-input' placeholder='Username' name='username' type='text' onChange={this.onInputChange}/>
              <br/>
              Password:<br/>
              <input className='login-input' id='password' name='password' type='password' onChange={this.onInputChange}/>
              <input type='submit'>Submit</input>
            </form>

          </LoginStyle>
        </Modal.Content>
        <Modal.Actions>
          <Button color='green' onClick={() => {
            this.logIn()
          }}>
            Log in
          </Button>
        </Modal.Actions>

      </Modal>

    )
  }
}

const LoginStyle = s.div `
    .field {
      display: flex !important;
      align-items: center;
      margin-bottom: .25em;
    }
    .login-input-label {
      margin-right: 1em;
      width: 60px;
    }
    .login-input {
      width: 300px;
    }
`

export default Login
```

Now when a user clicks the button for login, safari and chrome offer to save the password - but Firefox does not. I am using the latest version of all three browsers.

I tried tweaking the browser settings according to the official docs, running in safe mode and turning off hardware acceeration. The best result was saving the username in safe mode, but the password was ignored.

I also tried adding `onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()} autoComplete="on"` and a hidden `<input type="submit" value="Submit" className='login-submit' />`, but the end results are the same.

If it's any help, my app is hosted on a https server, while I develop in http. Chrome and safari will not save the password for the hosted app, but will for localhost.

Comment: That's the browser setting!

Comment: Ugh, forgot to mentioned. I tweaked the browser settings according to the docs, but the most I could get it to do was saving the username in safe mode.

Otherwise it just ignores the fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the form's onSubmit event was never actually triggered, so the browser did not recognize the form. This is the final version I came up with, but it could also be achieved by triggering the submit event with a ref from an external button:

Login function:

```
logIn = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault()
    const {username, password} = this.state
    if (username === 'blah' && password === 'blah') {
      this.props.uiStore.isLoggedIn = true
    } else {
      this.setState({incorrectCredentials: true})
    }

  }
```

The form:

```
<form ref='loginForm' autoComplete="on" onSubmit={this.logIn}>
              <div className='login-input-field'>
              <label className='login-input-label'>Username:</label>
              <input className='login-input' placeholder='Username' name='username' type='text' onChange={this.onInputChange}/>
              </div>
              <div className='login-input-field'>
              <label className='login-input-label'>Password:</label>
              <input className='login-input' name='password' type='password' onChange={this.onInputChange}/>
            </div>
              <div className='login-submit-container'>
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" className='login-submit' />
              </div>
</form>
```